# Cannot save session. Node, Mongo, GCP App Engine

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-platform

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(setExpireHeaders);
const uri = MONGODB_URI;
const client = new MongoClient(MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const store = new MongoDBStore({
    uri: uri,
    collection: 'sessions',
    autoReconnect: true,
    autoRemove: 'native' // Default
  });
store.on('error', function(error) {
    console.error('Session store error:', error);
  });
app.use(session({
    secret: JWT_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: store,
    cookie: { secure: true, sameSite: 'none' }
  }));
```

Cannot get MongodDB to store sessions. My node app is deployed on GCP APP Engine and the DB is MongoDB Atlas. Not sure what to change.
`mongodb+srv://user:pass` this is the format of the connection string. The user creation etc all works fine, but the sessions collection is empty. Have tried numerous changes to DB client creation, store creation, variations of connection strings, but nothing is helping save sessions. How to proceed?

EDIT:- So since this app is on GCP. GAE is not sending the cookie. That is causing all this. Cannot find a solution to this.